# Constant increment in PHP

Tags: php, html, forms

We have a registration form for a service on our website. For that form we want a unique reference number which should keep on incrementing. For example **FM00001** , **FM00002** and so on.

How can this be achieved in PHP. Is there a way to save a Global variable that can be incremented on a successful submission and then retrieved later for new form.

Comment: Usually you use a transactional database with an automatically incrementing column type, such as MySQL.

Comment: is the `FM` portion always present, or do those letters vary and have different sequences for each letter combo?

Comment: Its just a notation kind of thing. It has nothing to do with the increment. Sorry for creating the confusion. Just treat it as 1,  2, 3 and so on

Comment: especially if your registration form is written to a database, you already have all the mechanisms there to do what you need. If you aren't using databases at all, you could hold the info in a file or something simple.

Comment: I will be saving all the info on a CSV text file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would store the number in a database and then increment it. Or simpler use a textfile.

Textfile could be performed by:

```
//read
$f = @fopen("count.txt","r");
if(!$f) die ("File could not be opened");
$count = fgets($f,9);
fclose($f);

$count++;

//write
$f = @fopen("count.txt","w");
if(!$f) die ("File could not be written");
fwrite($f,$count);
fclose($f);
```

Comment: textfile works, but considering the complications I'd hardly call it "simple."

Comment: I would like to use the textfile option

Comment: @Jeremy J Starcher Well if you dont have a database server then its simpler.

Comment: flatfiles are pointless when things like sqlite are available.

Comment: this solution is not i/o safe. you should use file locking.

Comment: this seems good. What is 9 ? Is it for the length to read in file.

Comment: Well yes I used 9 for max length. But you can use any

Comment: I have used your file solution only. Thanks for the fast answer

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways of doing this in PHP...

A table with an auto-incrementing field easiest, if you are running a database.

Another option is to use file locking and read/write a local file.  Note that file locking doesn't work over `NFS` mounts and thus will fail in many popular shared hosting setups.

There are `NFS` locking work-arounds which involve creating and removing a directory entry...

Hmm.. do you need them incrementing in a sequential way, or is having the next number larger than the old number good enough?  Depending on the hosting setup, you **may** be able to get the current time stamp and use that as a unique ID.

Comment: The site is in magento and has its db. I am creating this form as a standalone. Can i use that DB. Won't i need to go through all the connectionstring and all

Comment: Afraid I took one look at Magento, ran away and built my own.  Personally, I'd create another database and use it, rather than piggybacking onto anything existing -- that way you are isolated from changes.

Comment: I need them in a sequential manner because i will be using the number for naming the upload files and matching the data. With TimeStamp things will be horrible. It will be vary hard to match the uploaded file with the correct info